# How to specify an icon for exe file which is different from the title bar icon when using NSIS to create an installer?

Tags: nsis

I'm using NSIS to create my own installer, I know we can use the instruction:
`!define MUI_ICON path_to_icon_file.ico`
to set the icon for the installer. But it sets both the title bar icon and the exe file icon. How can I set them separately with different icons?

Comment: In 25 years, I have never seen a Windows application that does that. However, within your icon file you can specify different icons for different sizes.

Comment: @idleberg yes it's not common but anyway, Anders has helped me solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually use the same icon but you can force a different icon if you must:

```
!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-install.ico" ; Exe icon
!define CUSTOMWINDOWICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\win-install.ico"
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT SetMyCustomIcon
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function SetMyCustomIcon
InitPluginsDir
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\cust.ico" "${CUSTOMWINDOWICON}"
!define /IfNDef LR_LOADFROMFILE 0x10
!define /IfNDef LR_DEFAULTSIZE 0x40
!define /IfNDef WM_SETICON 0x80
System::Call 'USER32::LoadImage(p 0,t "$PluginsDir\cust.ico", i 1, i 16, i 16, i ${LR_LOADFROMFILE})p.r0'
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_SETICON} 0 $0
System::Call 'USER32::LoadImage(p 0,t "$PluginsDir\cust.ico", i 1, i 0, i 0, i ${LR_LOADFROMFILE}|${LR_DEFAULTSIZE})p.r0'
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_SETICON} 1 $0
FunctionEnd
```

When NSIS 3.05 comes out you can embed the icon as a resource:

```
!define CUSTOMWINDOWICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\win-install.ico"
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT SetMyCustomIcon

...

PEAddResource "${CUSTOMWINDOWICON}" "#Icon" "#1337"
Function SetMyCustomIcon
!define /IfNDef WM_SETICON 0x80
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetModuleHandle(p0)p.s'
System::Call 'USER32::LoadImage(p s, i 1337, i 1, i 0, i 0, i 0x8040)p.r0'
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_SETICON} 1 $0
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: By the way, I would like to ask where I can find those instructions like "WM_SECTION" or "System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetModuleHandle(p0)p.s'", I can't find these commands in the NSIS user manual.

Comment: System::Call calls Windows functions directly, you must look them up on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ The System plug-in is documented in System.html